# Multiple Task running on non UI thread and running serially (not parallel)

Tags: wpf, task

I have a long running function . So I need to call this method on a background thread avoid blocking UI Thread.

Initially in the app I need to call this function multiple times but the process should be running in serial mode so only one Task running at the same time. 
Which is the best approach to this??

with this I know this will running on a non uiThread.

```
await Task.Run(() =>LoadMapLayer(layerType, opacity, filePath)));
```

But I think I don't understand properly how to work with multiple Task

Comment: Just call more tasks after each other...

Comment: But how I wait the first task to finish (without blocking the ui-thread)

Comment: if you need multiple tasks to wait for you can investigate methods like Task.WaitAll() or Task.WaitAny()

Answer (score 0):

You  may perhaps loop over all layers that should be loaded, either by a loop inside a single Task:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var layerType in layerTypes)
    {
        LoadMapLayer(layerType, opacity, filePath);
    }
});
```

Or by awaiting separate Tasks:

```
foreach (var layerType in layerTypes)
{
    await Task.Run(() => LoadMapLayer(layerType, opacity, filePath));
}
```